# RestTemplate "no suitable HttpMessageConverter"

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

i realize that something wired goes on with a project i try to create. I'm using the RestTemplate. And i'm trying to connect with a server and retrieve data. All went good until the time i decide to broke my program in more than one controller classes. Look what i did. In each one of these new classes i insert at each one of them:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate= new RestTemplate();
```

In order to retrieve data i'm using the JAXB annotations only(for data binding) and i can retrieve whatever i want. But when i'm trying to execute this line of code in the new class:

```
 ResponseEntity<AClass> result = restTemplate.exchange("url",
                        HttpMethod.GET, entity, AClass.class);
```

I'm taking this exception: RestClientException "Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [AClass] and content type [application/xml]"

If i put it back in the previous class can be executed without problem. Really i don't understand why. Probably because i'm using in the new class  a new RestTemplate.I try to declare  different RestTemplates and also to declare this way:@Autowired but the problem remains.  Should i declare something new in the dispatcher servlet?Moreover can i call in many classes the object restTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate()). Should i declare it in a specific class and call it from there? What should i do?I expect your propositions.

Answer (score 0):

How did you previously have your `restTemplate` instance set up? You have to register a `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter` with the `RestTemplate` instance, or it won't know how to unmarshal the XML. Something like this:

```
Jaxb2Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
// Make sure context paths includes AClass's package
jaxbMarshaller.setContextPaths("com.example.generated");
MarshallingHttpMessageConverter converter = new 
    MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(jaxbMarshaller, jaxbMarshaller);
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(Arrays.<HttpMessageConverter<?>> asList(converter));
```